# Desabilitando o mat-select após o filtro - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tenho um mat select que ao ser aberto um campo input acima dos itens listados no select, nesse campo input estou tendo um problema que ao ser pesquisado algo que não existe na lista e o select ser fechado, ele não abre mais, por exemplo se pesquisasse São Paulo e fechar o select, o select não seria aberto mais, segue os códigos e prints em anexo:

[image: input]

**HTML:**
`<input matInput placeholder="" [formControl]="filterControl" [maxLength]="255">`

**TYPESCRIPT:**

```
 filterControl = new FormControl();
  @Output() selectedFilter: GenericFilter[] = new Array<GenericFilter>();
  filteredOptions: Observable<GenericFilter[]>;
  lastFilter = '';

  ngOnInit(){
    this.filteredOptions = this.filterControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith<string | GenericFilter[]>(''),
      map((value) => (typeof value === 'string' ? value : this.lastFilter)),
      map((filter) => this.filter(filter))
    );
  }

filter(filter: string): GenericFilter[] {
    this.lastFilter = filter;
    if (filter) {
      return this.genericsFilter.filter((option) => {
        return (
          option.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0 ||
          option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        );
      });
    } else {
      return this.genericsFilter.slice();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Antes de fazer o primeiro map da função, você tem que limpar a variável `this.lastFilter` pois ela está com valor da ultima pesquisa, desta forma o mat-select sempre está pesquisando este valor que não existe.
Você também precisa adicionar um .subscribe(), pois o valuesChange() retorna um Observable